# DocUSign: How long does the app review process take?

Tags: docusignapi

We almost have an app which we will want to submit for review to DocUSign. Some stakeholders in the business - want to know a date for when we can launch our marketing site with DocUSign integration.

What is the best way to approach this. Do I simply "submit app for review" and take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Go Live Process](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/go-live/#:%7E:text=As%20part%20of%20the%20Go,minutes%20to%20hours%20to%20complete.&text=If%20playback%20doesn%27t%20begin%20shortly%2C%20try%20restarting%20your%20device.,-%E2%80%A2) . Once we submit the key for review it'll take atleast 15 to 20 minutes to complete.